# Trying to import under androidStudio a project using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, import

I'm using android studio and i'm trying to import a project(which is previous work on another computer) using openCV library. But there are some mistake of duplicate class. After clicking on the button import (Eclipse, gradle...) they show a window named Import Project from ADT, where I point to the D:\OpenCV\Android\OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk\sdk letting empty the first case.

Then I compile and it bring me two errors:

Error:(9, 8) error: duplicate class: org.opencv.R

Error:(9, 8) error: duplicate class: org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface

so I tried to stop to release the compile for the module openCvLibrary but the error:

duplicate class: org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface still remaining...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I import the wrong files, the folder which should be imported is apk then just put in the build gradle:

`android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }`